# irsock programming and visual c++ 12

Tags: c++

I want develop some irDA sockets applications, I am using:

compiler:   visual c++ 2013.
platform:   windows 7 x64

It seem s to me that something went wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <af_irda.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
WSADATA wSaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wSaData);

int sockServ = socket(AF_IRDA, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockServ == SOCKET_ERROR)   //this condition succeeds which means creating socket failed!??
    cout<<"Failed to create socket!  " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

DEVICELIST devLst;
devLst.   = 0;
int len = sizeof(devLst;);
int rc = getsockopt(sockServ,SOL_IRLMP,IRLMP_ENUMDEVICES,(char*)&devLst,&devLst);
//rc also = -1;

WCE_IAS_QUERY wceIasQuery; // Error: WCE_IAS_QUERY is undefined

//...

return 0;
}
```

I'd like explanation:

1- why socket creation failed?

2- why getsockopt failed?

3- why WCE_IAS_QUERY is undeclared identifier?

4- what are the pre-requisites for irSock programming?

thank you guys!

Comment: Check all your return codes and if you want to know why a call failed tell us what it returned.  Do you have infrared port and driver installed?

Comment: How are we supposed to guess the `WSAGetLastError()` value? You know better than us why socket creation failed.

Comment: it WSAGetLastError() returns 10047. I have macbook pro 8.1 I saw in device management: apple IR receiver.